# list indices must be integers or slices, not str - adding JSON file to MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I have converted a CSV file into JSON and I am currently trying to create a MongoDB from my JSON file.

```py
url = "mongodb://localhost:27017"

client = MongoClient(url)

db = client.york

collection = db.inventory

with open ('Inventory.json') as f:
    datastore = json.loads(f.read())

for data in datastore['inventory']:
    collection.insert_one(data)
```

---

Error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>        35     datastore = json.loads(f.read())
>        36 
>   ---> 37 for data in datastore['inventory']:
>        38     collection.insert_one(data)
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: You should include what datastore is exactly in your question (just print it) for more precise help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

client = MongoClient( "mongodb://localhost:27017")

db = client['york']

collection_client = db['inventory']

with open ('Inventory.json') as f:
    datastore = json.loads(f.read())

collection_client.insert_many(datastore)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do

```
for data in datastore['inventory']:
```

As the error says: `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`. You probably want your datastore to be a dictionary that contains the `'inventory'` key.

Comment: Can you explain how i would do that? Really new to python